# Oracle 11g Select query returns NO ROW SELECTED but the table actually has data

Tags: oracle, security, select

In my production, There is a table named `ABC` under `X` schema. I have granted `SELECT` privilege on `ABC` table to another user named `Z`. When I execute the query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM X.ABC;
```

as user `Z` it gives the following result

[image]

But when I query the same command

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ABC;
```

as user `X`, it shows:

[image]

Even if I query `SELECT * FROM X.ABC;` as the `Z` user it shows `no row selected` where I get the full data from `X` user.

What might be the reason of this issue?

The DB is ORACLE 11.2.0.1.0 Enterprise Edition.
This DB has also Database Vault enabled.

Comment: please do a `select owner, object_type from all_objects where object_name='ABC' order by owner, object_type ;` for both users and show us the result. If X.ABC is a view then the result can depend of the user accessing the view, There is [Fine-Grained Access Control](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/security.htm#CNCPT1592) that allows you to restrict a result set a user can see. You say that Database Vault is enabled so the security requirements seem to be very high, so I think this might be the intended behavior that a user cannot see all data.

Comment: Object type is TABLE for both of the users.

Comment: @miracle173 Yes, might be an intended behavior to control access. But what is the way to solve this ? any idea ? I am totally new to Oracle Securities.

Comment: Check user_policies under X user. If table ABC has VPD policy enabled, then you will see it. Also you can see the name of a policy function, look inside function and you will understand restrictions it set.

Comment: @EduardOkhvat yeah, I found 6 rows in user_policies of X user. That ABC table is also listed under object_name. There is a common policy for all those 6 tables and the policy owner is LBACSYS (label security) user. So how can I modify that policy ?

Comment: I worked long ago with Label Security, and do not remember anything :) 
See examples on    https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/security/ols/ols_otn.htm